# Simple function to generate a list of letters

Tags: python, strings, random

I would like get some suggestions for improvement of this function, and alert me about any dodgy practices that you find. 
I have been trying to learn python for a short time now and I would like to get some pointers on writing more pythonic code before I develop bad habits.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase
from random import choice

def get_letters(case, n, random = False):
    """
    A function to generate a list of letters 

    PARAMETERS
    ----------------------
    case (str) - type of case, 'u' for uppercase, 'l' for lowercase
    n (int) - number of letters to return
    random (bool) - specify if letters should be in random order

    RETURNS
    ----------------------
    if case is 'u', returns a list of uppercase letters
    if case is 'l', returns a list of lowercase letters
    if random = True a list of random letters will be returned (default is false)
    """

    case = case.lower()

    if random:
            if case == 'u':
                letters = [choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(n)]
            else:
                if case == 'l':
                    letters= [choice(ascii_lowercase) for i in range(n)]
    else:
        if case == 'u':
            letters = [ascii_uppercase[i] for i in range(n)]
        else:
            if case == 'l':
                letters= [ascii_lowercase[i] for i in range(n)]

    return letters
```

Comment: you might want to wait a bit (24h for instance) before accepting my answer: other users might have better suggestions! (but might not take the time to write them down if they see that an answer has already been accepted)

Comment: thanks for the tip @oliverpool - also, thanks for the pointer to yield. I had not heard of it before. I did some googleing and found https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/ as well. Very helpful.

Comment: How do you intend to call this function, and what would you do with the result?

Answer (score 3):

Some notes on your code:

- `def f(arg = False)` -> `def f(arg=False)` (PEP8)
- `case = case.lower()` Usually it's not a good idea to reuse variables: new values, new variable names.
- `else` + *indent* + `if` = `elif`
- Use `(true_value if condition else false_value)` for short conditional expressions.
- `ascii_uppercase[i] for i in range(n)`. This will fail if n is greater than the size of letters.
- `[choice(alphabet) for i in range(n)]`. This repeats characters, is that ok? It seems more fitting to use `random.sample(alphabet, n)`, which does not repeat elements.
- `case`: It's not idiomatic to send strings this way. Use a boolean argument instead (as @oliverpool proposed).

I'd write:

```
from random import sample
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase

def get_letters(n, random=False, uppercase=False):
    """Return n letters of the alphabet."""
    letters = (ascii_uppercase if uppercase else ascii_lowercase)
    return (sample(letters, n) if random else list(letters[:n]))
```

Comment: [sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=sample#random.sample) seems a good idea, but it changes slightly the behavior of the OP since the returned elements are unique (sampling without replacement) [btw the `list(...)` is not needed]. List slicing is also much nicer than my proposition (and doesn't fail in case of index "overflow").

Comment: @oliverpool: yes, it was intentional, I'll add a note.

Comment: The conversion to a list can be postponed. I suggest writing `list(letters[:n])` instead of `letters = list(…)`.

Comment: @200_success: you are right, I thought `sample` needed a list, updating.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think your variable names are quite good and it is nice that you use a docstring.

### Exception handling and corner cases

You should check the arguments and raise an exception in case the `case` is neither `u` nor `l` (calling your code with `w` crashes...).

And if your call your function with a greater number than there are letters in the alphabet, how should your function behave? Adding a [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html?highlight=doctest#module-doctest) for such cases seems a good idea!

### Suggestions

Instead of a letter, you could use a boolean and rename it to `uppercase`.

You can see that there is a lot of similarities between your branches, you could refactor them like this:

```
if uppercase:
    alphabet = ascii_uppercase
else:
    alphabet = ascii_lowercase
```

And then use `alphabet`:

```
if random:
    letters = [choice(alphabet) for i in range(n)]
else:
    letters = [alphabet[i] for i in range(n)]
```

And if you want to go further in python, instead of returning a list you can make an [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) (which returns an iterator). The following should work fine for python 3:

```
if random:
    yield from (choice(alphabet) for i in range(n))
else:
    yield from (alphabet[i] for i in range(n))
```

And if the caller need a list, he can do `list(get_letters(...))`